# Run PHP function after approve payment in Authorize.net

Tags: php, function, laravel-4, authorize.net

I just wanted to find a way to run a function after approved payment in Authorize.net.
All i want is to send email & save the response to database.
I've tried all i forum i saw about relay_url and reciept_url. 
These are my parameters:

```
public function getIndex(){
    //other declaration for SIM ....
    $fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id, $transaction_key,$amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp);
    $param = "";
    $param .="?x_login=".$api_login_id;
    $param .="?x_cancel_url=".URL::to('payment');
    $param .="&x_fp_hash=".$fingerprint;
    $param .="&x_amount=".$amount;
    $param .="&x_fp_timestamp=".$fp_timestamp;
    $param .="&x_fp_sequence=".$fp_sequence;
    $param .="&x_version=3.1";
    $param .= "&x_show_form=payment_form";
    $param .="&x_test_request=false";
    $param .="&x_invoice_num=".$fp_sequence;
    //$param .="&x_receipt_link_url=".URL::to('authonet/run_func_after_approve');
    //$param .="&x_relay_url=".URL::to('authonet/run_func_after_approve');
    //$param .="&x_relay_always=true";
    $param .="&x_method=cc";

    return Redirect::to("https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll".$param);
}
```

But after the payment, the customer is still in "Authorize.net thank you page" and they need to click the header "Back to site" to get back to my site. How can i run PHP function automatically without clicking the "Back to site" link?

Comment: I think there must be an option in authorize.net to do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, the uncomment line was the options that they gave to me but still i don't think that's the best practice. That option throwing me an error when the function runs more that 20 secs. I may not be able to send multiple mail in that short period of that.

Comment: And what if you set the relay to false?